# XSL apply more than one template

Tags: xslt

I'm transforming an XML document with PHP/XSL.  I'm searching for a keyword value.  I want to add paging, so I'm not returning all the search results.  I can do this with separate xsl files, but I'd like to join them if I can.  How can I return the search results and then apply the paging? E.g.

**Paging**

```
...
<xsl:if test="position() &gt; $start and position() &lt; $end">
...
```

**Search.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
<items>
<xsl:attribute name="count"><xsl:value-of select="count(//item)"/></xsl:attribute>
<xsl:apply-templates select="//item">
    <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$sortBy]" order="{$order}" data-type="{$type}" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
</items>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//item">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(
                 translate(title, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), $keyword) 
                    or contains(translate(content, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), $keyword)">
            <item>
                <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
                <content><xsl:value-of select="content"/></content>
                <date><xsl:value-of select="date"/></date>
                <author><xsl:value-of select="author"/></author>
                <uri><xsl:value-of select="uri"/></uri>
                <division><xsl:value-of select="division"/></division>
            </item>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Final Solution using xsl-variable and node-set()**

Need to do some more checks, but i'm pretty sure this works ok.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="searchResults">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//item">
        <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$sortBy]" order="{$order}" data-type="{$type}" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="//item">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(translate(title, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), $keyword) or contains(translate(content, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), $keyword)">
            <item>
                <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
                <content><xsl:value-of select="content"/></content>
                <date><xsl:value-of select="date"/></date>
                <author><xsl:value-of select="author"/></author>
                <uri><xsl:value-of select="uri"/></uri>
                <division><xsl:value-of select="division"/></division>
            </item>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//item" mode="paging">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() &gt; $start and position() &lt; $end">
            <item>
                <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
                <content><xsl:value-of select="content"/></content>
                <date><xsl:value-of select="date"/></date>
                <author><xsl:value-of select="author"/></author>
                <uri><xsl:value-of select="uri"/></uri>
                <division><xsl:value-of select="division"/></division>
            </item>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <items>
        <xsl:attribute name="count"><xsl:value-of select="count(//item)"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($searchResults)/*" mode="paging" />
    </items>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Read about [modes](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#modes) in XSLT**.

Then use in these two cases:

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="search" select="someExpression">
 <!-- <xsl:with-param> children if necessary -->
 <!-- <xsl:sort> children if necessary -->
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

and also:

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="paging" select="someExpression">
 <!-- <xsl:with-param> children if necessary -->
 <!-- <xsl:sort> children if necessary -->
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Of course, you must have tempaltes in each of the above modes.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, but can i select the same node e.g. select="//item" in both templates?

Comment: @rossjha: The node for which a template is selected is determined by the `<xsl:apply-template>` instruction first, then the template's match pattern must match the node and it must have highest import precedence and then priority. The short answer is that the templates will be selected for execution, but not both with a single `<xsl:apply-templates>`. You need to have two separate `<xsl:apply-templates>` instructions: `<xsl:apply-templates mode=""search" select="yourExpression"/>` and `<xsl:apply-templates mode=""paging" select="yourExpression"/>`

Comment: Sorry not getting this.  Could you give an example?  Tried adding     `<xsl:apply-templates mode=""search" select="yourExpression"/>` and `<xsl:apply-templates mode=""paging" select="yourExpression"/>` but this doesn't work

Comment: I ended up adding the search results to a variable and using node-set, which seems to work great.  Thanks for you help.  [You answer on this questions was also useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678353/apply-xslt-transform-to-an-already-transformed-xml).

Comment: @rossjha: You are welcome. Seems I was sleeping and couldn't answer your last comment :). Yes, I'd have suggested a combination of two-step processing and using different modes in each of the two steps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is no ways to apply different templates consequentially in single transformation. So, try to add paging xpath to search xpath:

```
<xsl:when test="contains(
             translate(title, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), $keyword) 
                or contains(translate(content, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), $keyword)
                and
                position() &gt; $start and position() &lt; $end">
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels to me like a case where you should split the transformation into two phases, one to do searching and one to do paging.

You can either writing a pipeline that executes two transformations written as separate stylesheets, or (with a bit of help from `exslt:node-set()`) you can do it in a single stylesheet saving the results in a temporary variable. I'd recommend two stylesheets - it makes the code more readable and reusable.

Comment: Hi could you give me an example writing a pipline?  Sounds intresting.