# using more than one apply-templates with the same select filter

Tags: xslt-1.0

I would like to apply some templates to my xml using apply-templates, but I can't seem to work out how to have more than one template type per "data type".
For example, with this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
<item name='1'>
first
</item>
<item name='2'>
second
</item>
<item name='3'>
third
</item>
</items>
```

I use the following xslt to get the output I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" />

<xsl:template match="items/item">
    <xsl:value-of select='.'></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/"> 
    <html> 
      <body>
      <font color="blue">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item[@name='1']"></xsl:apply-templates>
      </font>
      <font color="red">      
      <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item[@name='1']"></xsl:apply-templates>
      </font>
      </body> 
    </html> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <body><font color="blue">
         first
         </font><font color="red">
         first
         </font></body>
</html>
```

The first item colored blue followed by the same item colored red.  But with this, I still end up with a lot of cut-n-paste boilerplate that I would love to move into the template "items/item", but I can't figure out how to get the same template to select one of the two colors.  Is there a way to do this with out the  wrappers in the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is quite similar, but perhaps not as clear:

[XSL apply more than one template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153442/xsl-apply-more-than-one-template)

If you use the "mode" attribute in xsl:template, you can specialize the template with the same select attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" />

<xsl:template match="items/item" mode="blue">
    <font color="blue"><xsl:value-of select='.'></xsl:value-of></font>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="items/item" mode="red">
    <font color="red"><xsl:value-of select='.'></xsl:value-of></font>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/"> 
    <html> 
      <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item[@name='1']" mode="blue"></xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item[@name='1']" mode="red"></xsl:apply-templates>
      </body> 
    </html> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should allow you to move the red and blue font wrappers into the template definition and allow you to chose them based on the mode attribute.