# Can I ignore namespaces with XSLT and then perform more transformations in the same stylesheet?

Tags: xslt, namespaces

The following transform templates properly remove namespaces from my input document:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::*)]">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there a way to continue processing the "namespace stripped" output in the same 
stylesheet to achieve further transformations?  e.g. use xsl:copy or nested templates 
or something of that nature?  Or do I have to do transform chaining?

Comment: Mea Culpa - answer is provided here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678353/apply-xslt-transform-to-an-already-transformed-xml

Answer (score 1):

I believe "exclude-result-prefixes" is what you are looking for in the XSLT declaration.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_stylesheet.asp

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  exclude-result-prefixes= only prunes unwanted namespace nodes from the result elements in the stylesheet and has no effect on the nodes from the source tree.